Azure Keyvault not loaded by Dapr Client during Asp net core web api app start
In Azure Container apps; I have configured the Dapr Components and have assigned all System Identity permissions as shown:

In the ASP Net Core WebApi Startup or program.cs I have added below code:
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

     // Add services to the container.

     builder.Services.AddControllers();
     // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
     builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
     builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
     builder.Configuration.AddDaprSecretStore("keyvault", new DaprClientBuilder().Build(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

     var app = builder.Build();

And I have a controller as shown:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    IConfiguration m_Configuration;

    public HelloController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        m_Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // GET: api/<HelloController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //using var client = new DaprClientBuilder().Build();
        //var result = client.GetBulkSecretAsync("keyvault").Result;

        return Ok(JsonSerializer.Serialize<IConfiguration>(m_Configuration));
    }
}

if I deploy above app in a container to container apps; it successfully deploys and when I visit/shoot API
GET /api/hello

then response is Empty i.e IConfiguration is empty
However; when I remove below line from Program.cs
 builder.Configuration.AddDaprSecretStore("keyvault", new DaprClientBuilder().Build(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

and uncomment below line in Controller Method:
 using var client = new DaprClientBuilder().Build();
 var result = client.GetBulkSecretAsync("keyvault").Result;

and then deploy. Upon shooting the same endpoint; the keyvault data is loaded and response is correct.
What am I doing wrong?
Basically I want the IConfiguraiton to be filled in with all KeyVault data during application start.
.NET 8.0
Dapr.AspNetCore 1.13.1
Dapr.Extensions.Configuration 1.13.1
Thanks

Are you trying to read the secret from the Azure Key vault in Asp.net web API with Dapr and push that to the Docker container?
